# Android Studio 2.2 (Beta) - How do I add a jar file in this version?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

So I installed Android Studio 2.2 (beta) and there isn't the option to add a  directory and left me with the options of adding a Module or Resource Directory. So I'm wondering how I add in a jar file (protobuf) into my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a folder called libs. Paste your .jar file there.
Open gradle module and paste this :

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
```

Now every sync your new .jar file in the libs folder will be synced with your project.
This is taken from a similiar post : 
[Android Studio: Add jar as library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library)

Comment: That was my problem. I didn't look at the folder structure outside of Android Studio.